# Overtone volume controls in ubuntu have no effect

Tags: audio, ubuntu, clojure, jack

I just finished installing Overtone on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook pro. Let's leave aside for a moment that a reasonable person would simply boot into OSX for any audio processing.

I kill pulseadio, start jackd like so,

```
jackd -r -d alsa -r 44100 -P # same results without the -P
```

`cd` into the overtone dir (tried both clone of 0.8-dev and including 0.7.1 in dependencies.clj), and start a `lein repl`. So far so good.

`(use 'overtone.core)`, `(boot-external-server)`, and `(boot-server)` all seem to work fine. Now the problem comes when I run code like this,

```
(definst foo [] (saw 220))
(definst bar [] (* 0.001 (saw 220)))
(foo) # works like it should
(stop)
(bar) # makes exactly the same sound and volume level as foo
(stop)
```

Multiplying the `saw` ugen by a number doesn't seem to affect the volume. Any idea what I should try or what output I should check?

--edit--

I also tried dropping down to sclang and got similar results:

```
{ SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.00001) }.play;
```

Sounds the same as

```
{ SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.9) }.play;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this post on the jack website](http://jackaudio.org/macbook_distortion).

> As of April 2012 there seems to be driver problem that affects the audio interface on the Macbook when it is used in 24 or 32 bit mode. To avoid the resulting distortion, use the -S flag to the ALSA backend to force it to use 16 bit sample data format.

I fixed the problem by first starting jack with the following command:

```
jackd -r -d alsa -S -r 44100
```

or

```
sudo jackd -R -d alsa -S -r 44100
```

then launching sclang.